# How to set path for 'Header Search path' when adding 3rd party library to iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode4.2

I want to add a 3rd party library [Speech-To-Text](https://github.com/todoroo/iPhone-Speech-To-Text)to my `Xcode` project. I just drag `xcodeproj` file in my iPhone project.Then I did follow steps like Target Dependencies,Link Binary with libraries and set Header Search path. But I confused in how to set Header search Path properly.Then I import `#import SpeechToTextModule.h`' that time i got error like `SpeechToTextModule.h` **file not found**.Please help me.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Did you add the `libSpeechToText.a` ?

Comment: @MidhunMP,Yes i did it..But I am confuse in setting path of 'Header Search Path'...

Comment: I think the below answer will work for you, if not can you please post the path given by you for that field ?

Comment: @MidhunMP,path is '/Users/user/Desktop/SpeechText/'

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Following are the steps to add header search path for external 3rd party libraries :

1. Select build settings of project
2. Select Header Search Paths property from settings
3. Add header directory, dont forget last `/`and surrounding quotes

Comment: My path is 'Users/user/Desktop/MyCal/SpeechText/' but it's not working.

Comment: It should include all header files, Can you try to add your library folder within your project folder and try with it?

Comment: Your path is valid, but while compiling if it is relative to project then it wont create much problem. while in case of absolute, it should be referred exactly same all over the project.

Comment: I was needed to add double quotes to work. And to set basic root use "$(SRCROOT)/yr_folder"

Comment: I'm in the situation where the entire "Header Search Paths" item is missing. How can I create that?

Comment: Thanks much Vinay for keeping me honest.  These details are normally what I require from others as well.  Xcode 5.1.1 (5B1008).

Answer (score 0):

For static library, along with library we need to add header files to Xcode project.