# Using App delegate / View Controllers of one project in another project

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a situation where I need to make a branded app for different users and the requirement is such that I create different iOS app for each user. I have all my code (`AppDelegate` and all `ViewControllers` and its implementation files) in one main xcode project.

I have created new empty xcode project and I have included my main project in this new project. Now I want my new empty xcode project to run in the way as if I am using my main project. So, How can I use the main project's app delegate and its starting `ViewController` from my new empty `Xcode` project?

Comment: Could various target in the same project be a solution, instead of creating various projects?

Comment: No, my project has only single target. I want to create different project and use flow of my main project in all different projects.

Comment: You need to add AppDelegate from project B to search header path in build settings. Something like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195357/how-to-set-path-for-header-search-path-when-adding-3rd-party-library-to-iphone#comment21410916_15195357).

Answer (score 1):

In your main.m class import the AppDelegate class from your other project and than launch it

```
#import <OtherProject/AppDelegate.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. Also is there a way to do this if I use a Static library of my main project instead of including the entire project?

Comment: hmm.. i don't know if it is possible to create a static library from a complete ios application. i never actually done that but i could imagine that to be a problem.